# Scala mock when/thenReturn Future null

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, scalatest

I am trying to test my code with scalatestplus-play(4.0.3). I also use mockito-core(3.7.7). My test code doesnt work. it ends with exception like;

```
[info]   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "scala.concurrent.Future.flatMap(scala.Function1, scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)" because "this.future" is null
[info]   at core.utils.Extensions$GetOrFail.getOrFailWith(Extensions.scala:12)
[info]   at services.ShowcaseService.update(ShowcaseService.scala:42)
[info]   at services.ShowcaseServiceSpec.$anonfun$new$5(ShowcaseServiceSpec.scala:59)
[info]   at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
[info]   at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
[info]   at org.scalatest.WordSpecLike$$anon$3.apply(WordSpecLike.scala:1075)
```

Also my test code;

```
    val showcase = Showcase("id", "title", None, StrategyType.manuel, active = false, RecordTime())
    val updatedShowcase = Showcase("id", "titleChange", Option("descChange"), StrategyType.manuel, active = false, RecordTime())

    val showcaseUpdateRequest: ShowcaseUpdateRequest = ShowcaseUpdateRequest(Option("titleChange"), Option("descChange"))

    val id = "id"
    when(showcaseRepository.findOneById(id)).thenReturn(Future(Some(showcase)))
    when(showcaseRepository.update(showcaseUpdateRequest, id)).thenReturn(Future(updatedShowcase))

    val result = showcaseService.update(showcaseUpdateRequest, id)
```

Showcase Service;

```
  def update(req: ShowcaseUpdateRequest, id: ShowcaseId): Future[Showcase] = for {
    _ <- showcaseRepository.findOneById(id).getOrFailWith(ShowcaseNotFoundException(id))
    updatedShowcase <- showcaseRepository.update(req, id)
  } yield updatedShowcase
```

Lastly the implicit class that the error occurs;

```
  implicit class GetOrFail[T](future: Future[Option[T]]) {
    def getOrFailWith[E <: Throwable](ex: E)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = future flatMap {
      case None => Future.failed(ex)
      case Some(t) => Future.successful(t)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show where you create the class `GetOrFail`? It seems that you create it with a `null`

Comment: @TomerShetah I already showed it in description and created it implicitly.

Comment: There are still missing details to help you. Cann you please add a complete test? We need a [mre].

Comment: @TomerShetah Can you please check again ?

Answer (score 0):

According to stack trace problem occurs because mocked `showcaseRepository.update` returns `null`, which happens because mockito returns `null` every time when any mocked arguments does not match with arguments actual received.

One of the way's to go: use `doAnswer` and `any` to return `Future.failed` for any unexpected arguments to fail test:

```
// Leave for expected result
when(showcaseRepository.update(showcaseUpdateRequest, id)).thenReturn(Future(updatedShowcase))

// For all unexpected arguments
doAnswer(args => Future.failed(new Exception("Unexpected arguments for `update`: $args"))).when(showcaseRepository).update(any, any)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting `null` from `showcaseRepository.findOneById(id)`.

Most likely, it happens because with a different argument, that what you gave to the mock (it looks like you have some implicit conversion going on there, because your `id` is a String, but the function seems to want `ShowcaseId`).

So, when you do:
`when(showcaseRepository.findOneById(id)).thenReturn(Future(Some(showcase)))`
it basically says "when `findOneById` is called *with this exact parameter*, I want it to return this value".

But depending on how your implicit conversion is implemented, the value of `ShowcaseId` you end up calling that function with may end up being different from what you had when setting up the mock.

It can also be the case, that your code is doing something wrong, and calling the function with a wrong value for the parameter, so the test is failing correctly, just in a way that is hard to interpret.

For this reason it is usually a good idea to never use actual parameter values when stubbing the calls, but instead `verify` them afterwards:

```
when(showcaseRepository.findOneById(any)).thenReturn(Future(Some(showcase))

... // do the test

verify(showcaseRepository).findOneById(id)
```

This setup will make `findOneById` *always* return that value, regardless of its argument, and then, if the function was actually called with a different parameter value, it will fail the `verify` with a meaningful message (like "called with this value instead of that value") rather than a cryptic NPE.

As a side note, `Future.successful(Some(showcase))` is a better way to create immediate futures.